# SQL Server - Daily Copy Task - only copy records that don't already exist (no unique identifier)

Tags: sql-server

We currently have a SQL Server 2016 Enterprise instance with a table of data which pulls from websites - approximated 30 fields per records, two of them with paragraphs-worth of unstructured data. (There is a unique identifier for each record, but read on to see why this won't do me any good).  I've been tasked with creating a 2nd SQL Server instance which will start as an exact copy of the first.  But Instance 1 and 2 will only be exact copies on Day 1.

From there, Instance 1 will have many daily writes and deletes, while Instance 2 will simply act as a retention archive of all records which have ever written to Instance 1.

Therefore, I'll need to set up a daily task which copies records from instance 1 to instance 2 only if the records don't already exist in instance 2.  Since the table in question has some unstructured data fields, I believe the only way to accomplish this is to compare every single field in a record incoming to Instance 2 to every field of every existing record as a duplicate checker, then only write the record if it doesn't already exist.

However where it really gets tricky is that Instance 1 does a full erase/replace each day - so records written to Instance 1 may very well have already been written to it (in fact, the majority of them have). Therefore, Integrated Change Tracking on Instance 1 does me no good.

So is the only way to accomplish this my aforementioned idea of one-by-one checking for duplicates?  I'm not asking for someone to write the statements for me, but rather just need some guidance on where I would even start with this.  I'm even open to 3rd party solutions that may exist that can accomplish this.  I'm thinking we can't be the first company that is trying to do this and there must be a logical solution for this (our biggest caveat being how unstructured our data is).

Many thanks.

Comment: How does Instance 1 perform its full erase/replace each day? Batch job? Bulk copy? Is it different than the daily writes/deletes which occur to it?

Comment: @Forty3 sorry, I should have been more clear - the daily writes/deletes and the erase/replace are really one and the same.  As far as how the erase/replace happens, it done via a SQL Server Agent job which runs a stored procedure on data in a temp holding table.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet for this is [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication).

It can be a little hairy-scary at times. But it is rock solid and very reliable.

For **smaller databases** you can easily get away with using [Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/snapshot-replication) Replication, running on some form of intermittent cycle. This reinitializes the subscriber from a newly minted snapshot of the distributor every instantiation.

If the database has any scale, I would recommend [Transactional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication) Replication, which will parse your log files and ship new transactions to the subscriber.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I've read all 3 links in your post.  I'm still a little shaky though on how I'll accomplish what I'm trying to do given the nature of the Instance 1 data.  Snapshot replication would not work (except for the very first sync) because if we take a snapshot of of Instance 1 and sync that to Instance 2, we will lose historical data on Instance 2. Now, Transactional replication is closer, but I still don't know it will work, given what I've read.  I only want the publisher to send records to the subscriber that the subscriber doesn't already have...b/c of the erase/

Comment: replace nature of the data going to the publisher, the publisher is going to have thousands of records written to it every day that the subscriber already has in it.  That's what I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.  But, perhaps Transactional Replication has a way to handle this?

Comment: @Stpete111 I wouldn't fret over the volume. Replication is very robust. I have a db setup to transactionally replicate from on-prem into azure which has MILLIONS of writes/updates per day, and even it performs admirably. The initialization from the snapshot will vary based on db size. But the log agent is very efficient even at scale. Worth a look!